# Docker-machine connect to existing AWS machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I have docker swarm cluster installed on AWS using cloudformation template provided by docker. (latest version)

How can I connect to one of swarm managers using docker machine ?

I’ve tried using docker machine AWS driver with all possible parameters , but I was not able to connect.

Also tried using docker machine general driver , it returns “os not supported”.

Any help will be greatly appreciated ,

Steps trying to connect:

puttygen my-key.pem -L > id_rsa

docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=ec2-....compute.amazonaws.com --generic-ssh-key id_rsa Swarm-Dev01

Running pre-create checks... Creating machine... (Swarm-Dev01) Importing SSH key... Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes... Detecting operating system of created instance... Waiting for SSH to be available...

Comment: Post the commands that you have tried

Comment: docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=ec2-....compute.amazonaws.com --generic-ssh-key id_rsa Swarm-Dev01

Answer (score 1):

its actually very simple.steps :-

1. From your existing docker machine copy the private key of remote host you want to connect to ie

`[ec2-user@ip-xx ~]$ docker-machine ls
NAME            ACTIVE   DRIVER      STATE     URL                       SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
somehost   -        amazonec2   Running   tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:2376           v17.07.0-ce`

Then to get the key path i do :-

`[ec2-user@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx ~]$ docker-machine inspect somehost
{
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "MachineName": "somehost",
        "SSHUser": "ubuntu",
        "SSHPort": 22,
        "SSHKeyPath": "/home/ec2-user/.docker/machine/machines/somehost/id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "/home/ec2-user/.docker/machine",
        "SwarmMaster": false,`

The private key path is in *SSHKeyPath*. Copy the private key to you other machine you want to connect to in my example am using an ec2-instance with docker-machine to launch host to another ec2-instance so if i want to copy the key i just use `scp` ie i will copy it like :

`jimmy@jimmy-Lenovo-G570:~/$ scp -r -i docker-machine-instance.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/.docker/machine/machines/somehost/id_rsa /home/docker-machine-aws`

2. Now on my laptop i can connect to that host using *generic driver* , like :-

`docker-machine create --driver generic \
 --generic-ip-address xx.xx.xx.xx \
 --generic-ssh-user ubuntu \
 --generic-ssh-key /home/docker-machine-aws/id_rsa \
 somehost-2`

Works like charm !

Comment: ```docker-machine inspect somehost``` is golden!!